# Difference in req.ip between express route and WebSocket

Tags: express, nginx

I have an Express based server, which provides routes, and also a websocket server. It seats right behind a nginx proxy. I see differences in req.ip, and am trying to understand where this is all coming from.

First, on my express setup, I have the following:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

On my express / route, my nginx is configured in part as follows:

```
        proxy_pass http://my-server-name;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

And on the /ws path:

```
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://my-server-name;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```

On the express / route, I get the following:

```
req.headers['x-real-ip']=150.150.150.150 
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']=0.0.0.0, 150.150.150.150 
req.connection.remoteAddress=::ffff:172.19.0.6 
req.ip=150.150.150.150
```

(I replaced my valid public IP address with that fake 150... address)

On the /ws path, I get:

```
req.headers['x-real-ip']=undefined 
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']=150.150.150.150 
req.connection.remoteAddress=::ffff:172.19.0.6 
req.ip=undefined
```

Why is req.ip undefined on the /ws path? Why does the x-forwarded-for display an additional 0.0.0.0 address on the / path? Thanks!